# preventDefault() won't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

Why will this refuse to work?
HTML stuff

```
<div id="nav-bar">  
  <ul>  
    <li>  
      <span>  
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>  
      </span>  
    </li>  
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Javascript stuff

```
$('div#nav-bar').filter('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you expecting vs. what is happening?

Comment: instead `filter` use `find` or `('div#nav-bar a')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filter only filters what is already selected. In your case, the `#nav-bar` element.

You need this:

```
$('div#nav-bar a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` is the wrong method to use here. you should either use `find` to look for elements in a selection:

```
$('div#nav-bar').find('a')...
```

or simply combine that into one selector:

```
$('div#nav-bar a')...
```

after you've fixed that, your `preventDefault` will actually get applied and work, theres nothing wrong with that piece of code directly.

Comment: `$('div#nav-bar').find('a')` is actually faster than `$('div#nav-bar a')` and I believe `$('#nav-bar').find('a')` is even faster.