# jquery not working with my html

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preventDefault() won't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162217/preventdefault-wont-work-for-me)

I have this HTML code

```
<div id="nav-bar">  
  <span>  
        <a href="check.html">check</a>  
      </span>  
</div>
```

Now i'm trying to bind click event for this anchor tag and using stopPropagation but it's not working.

```
$('div#nav-bar').filter('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you want [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `.filter()`?

Comment: Try replacing `filter` with `find` !

Comment: I think I saw same question sometime back..

Comment: my aplologies sir, i didnt see that question. how can i close it now?

Comment: Don't corrupt `event` with the global `event` object. Use `e` or `bananas` or anything. Can you also mention why you are trying to do this? It would add some weight to your question and keep it from being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing `.filter()`. That's for narrowing down your jQuery object's selections. `.find()` will look for matching elements *inside* the elements in your jQuery object (hence `$('div#nav-bar').find('a')` will look for `<a>` in `<div id="nav-bar">` elements).

However, you'll also find better mileage if you just use a direct selector outright:

```
$('#nav-bar a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The selector `#nav-bar a` selects all `<a>` elements inside `#nav-bar` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get `<a>` element from `#nav-bar`:

```
$('#nav-bar').find('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Another option is to [change the selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$('#nav-bar a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nav-bar a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nav-bar').on("click", "a", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You've got your delegate signature backwards. It's supposed to be `$('#nav-bar').on('click', 'a', function(event) { });`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.find()` nor do you need `e.preventDefault()`. (And obviously you don't need `.filter()`.

```
<div id="nav-bar">  
  <span>  
        <a href="#" data-url="check.html">check</a>  
      </span>  
</div>



$('div#nav-bar  a').click(function(){
   var url = $(this).data('url');
   window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: How will that cope without JS?

Comment: @devdigital: Hmmm. Point. Not-so-graceful degradation? :) But, what's the point of a link that goes nowhere in the first place?.. OP hasn't mentioned.